# Flash Object over position fixed element in chrome

Tags: html, css, flash, google-chrome, cross-browser

I have a absolute:position dropdown menu on the top right corner of the site ("Restaurantes"). And a flash header. On Firefox and IE I don't have any problem, but on Chrome the fixed drop down menu get behind the flash element.

The flash element already has the wmode:transparent parameter.

If I change the drop down menu postion to absolute it works, but i need it to be fixed.

You can find the site in this address:

http://ismapps.net/frisbysite/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by setting the `z-index` of `#flyout` to anything above `5`:

```
#flyout {
   padding: 0px;
   margin: 0px;
   list-style: none;
   position: fixed;
   right: 0px;
   top: 0;
   display: block;
   z-index: 6; /* This is the fix */
}
```

P.S: that's some tasty chicken :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, if you ever come to Colombia let me buy you some chicken. :)